# Is there an expression or idiom for something convenient that happens right when you need it to?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Especially if it's something unlikely. Almost as if it could only happen in a movie. For instance, you're about to be robbed and a random cop on patrol arrives at that exact time. What are the chances of that?

Is there an expression/idiom that communicates that general idea?

Comment: Not offering an expression, hence the comment rather than answer, but this sounds like a "coincidence" to me.

Comment: In AmE we usually describe such a happening as **blind luck**.

Comment: The cop arrived **in the nick of time**

Comment: @ScottBrown It would *be* a coincidence, but coincidences don't have to be fortuitous, they could just as easily be bad luck, or entirely neutral.

Comment: For describing an actual work of fiction, you could call it a [*deus ex machina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina) or [plot contrivance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrivance). You could apply these terms to real life ironically, if you desired. If you need a more specific term for a very exact type of contrivance, feel free to waste an afternoon (or day, or week) on [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContrivedStupidityTropes).

Comment: @Smig, "Miracle"?

Comment: @neminem A fortunate coincidence, then. I have actually heard "fortunate happenstance" before. But that's basically what serendipity means anyway, so I just upvoted that answer instead of posting a new one. :)

Comment: You already said it: "What are the chances?"

Answer (score 42):

The first word that comes to mind is [**serendipity**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serendipity). Merriam-Webster says:

> luck that takes the form of finding valuable or pleasant things that are not looked for

But as Robusto correctly points out, that word is mostly used for *discoveries*.
A thesaurus points from there to [**fluke**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fluke), defined by macmillan as:

> something that happens unexpectedly because of an accident or good luck

An alternative option, as [Brian Donovan](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256014/is-there-an-expression-or-idiom-for-something-convenient-that-happens-right-when/256015?noredirect=1#comment560420_256015) points out, is the *adjective* [**fortuitous**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortuitous), as Merriam-Webster describes:

> 2 a :  fortunate, lucky
>   b :  coming or happening by a lucky chance

Answer (score 22):

**Godsend** (*noun*):

- an unexpected thing or event that is particularly welcome and timely, as if sent by God  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/godsend)
- something good that happens unexpectedly, especially at a time when it is needed [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/godsend)

> *'The grant was a real godsend, especially considering the theatre was due to close next month.'*

Answer (score 10):

To further the idea of 'Something that could only happen in a movie, perhaps  *[Deus Ex Machina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina)*:

> Deus ex machina (Latin: [ˈdeʊs ɛks ˈmaː.kʰɪ.naː]: /ˈdeɪ.əs ɛks ˈmɑːkiːnə/ or /ˈdiːəs ɛks ˈmækɨnə/;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina) plural: dei ex machina) ... The term has evolved to mean a plot device whereby a seemingly unsolvable problem is suddenly and abruptly resolved by the contrived and unexpected intervention of some new event, character, ability or object.
>   *<sub>Wikipedia</sub>*

Answer (score 5):

[Stroke of Luck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/stroke-of-good-luck)

> A fortunate occurrence that could not have been predicted or expected

**Jim:** How'd you get a ticket to the game its been sold out for weeks?

**Tom:** A bicyclists happened to run into me this morning and took off. Afterwards I noticed the ticket on the ground, it must have fallen out of his pocket. What a stroke of luck right?

Comment: @MatthieuM. good catch :)

Answer (score 4):

For yet another expression with heavenly implications and origins, there’s

> [like manna from
>   heaven](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/manna+from+heaven),

meaning: “something that you need which you get when you are not expecting to get it.” (from Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed., as cited in The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

A common phrase for sudden good fortune, especially in the midst of poor fortune, is *stroke of luck*, e.g. "We were being robbed, but we had a stroke of luck: a police officer appeared." It's used in this sense as a noun meaning "an act or feat".

You might also consider using *happy coincidence*. The scenario you describe is a coincidence: the simultaneous occurrence of causally unrelated events which are relevant to each other. The fact that the coincidence results in a fortunate outcome (for the speaker, at least) makes it happy.

Answer (score 3):

To build further on Julie's `godsend`, you could say

The cop arriving was **[divine intervention](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=divine%20intervention)**.

> When a miracle happens. When the hand of God reaches down and saves someone from a life threatening or dangerous situation. <sub>(UD)</sub>
>
> When someone is placed in the right place at the right time to be a catalyst for someone in need, when the person in need may have been in angst about how they would get through a certain situation.

Surprisingly, Urban Dictionary is the only citation I could dig up.

---

Along the same lines, you can say that it was **[Providence](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/providence)**.

> Providence is the guardianship and care provided by a deity or god. Religious people thank their god for his providence. <sub>(Vocabulary.com)</sub>
>
> The word provide is a good clue to this word's meaning: when a religious being is said to give people providence, he's taking care of them — providing for them. For religious people, any good thing that happens to them — like landing a new job, getting healthy, or finding money on the ground — could be considered an example of providence. You can also talk about people providing providence, if they're showing care and prudence in managing resources.

Comment: there is also a very brief definition of 'divine intervention' under 'divine', at: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/divine)

Comment: @JulieCarter: Thanks. Very brief indeed. I think `godsend` should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It is serendipitous.-- "occurring by chance in a happy or beneficial way."

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Cynthia. *Serendipity* was already offered in a high quality answer. Would you care to make another suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**synchronicity**: A term coined by mystical psychologist Carl Jung to describe coincidences that seem to have deeper meaning and significance.

> the simultaneous occurrence of events that appear significantly related but have no discernible causal connection.
>   -Google

Comment: I understand this to mean a coincidence with personal meaning, such as happening across a photograph of a long-lost friend and then getting mail from them the next day. It wouldn't normally be used for plain good luck.

Comment: @PaulJohnson You're right. I generally think of "synchronicity" as meaning anything that a superstitious person would ascribe to prayer / psychic powers / magic / positive thinking / etc, but I believe it does technically have a more general meaning, for anything that can be made to look like a cause-effect relation but actually isn't. So, whether this term applies might depend on the beliefs of the person describing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **godsend**, though perhaps it's best to reserve this for when urgent needs are met.

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/godsend) has:

> *godsend*  n.
>
> Something wanted or needed that comes or happens unexpectedly.

How literal the term is people must decide for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

An **11th hour reprieve** is something that saves you from something bad at the last minute.

**Suddenly everything came up sevens** would when things suddenly start going your way.

Answer (score 0):

With a supernatural/superstitious element perhaps one of these fits:

> fate, fateful, twist of fate, written in the stars

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've heard **felicitous** used in this sense - "A felicitous occurrence".

Comment: And what does it mean?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен it means "lucky".

Answer (score 0):

My firs thought was **right place, right time**.

> in the location where something good is to happen exactly when it happens

Definition from [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+right+place+at+the+right+time)

I'm not sure that this works for your particular example, though it does work for the question title.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more common word, go with "convenient" (adjective) and "conveniently" (adverb)

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/convenient

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/conveniently

"I was about to be robbed, but conveniently a cop turned a corner just in the nick of time."
"That was convenient!"